# Query a model to include the sum of related transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, view, controller, sum

I have three models in my inventory app for Category, Item and Transaction. I have created a report that shows me what I'd like to know, but I suspect it's bad practice to have queries in the view. And I suspect that this is inefficient. Here is my current view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
<% @item_id_list.each do |item_id| %>
  <% item = Item.find(item_id) %>
  <% sum = Transaction.where(item_id: item_id).sum(:amount) %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.category.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.description %></td>
    <td><%= sum %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

And here is my current controller:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def current
    @item_id_list = Transaction.uniq.pluck(:item_id)
  end

end
```

And for reference, here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141029181100) do

  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "items", ["category_id"], name: "index_items_on_category_id"

  create_table "transactions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.string   "code"
    t.date     "date"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "transactions", ["item_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_item_id"

end
```

Can someone suggest a more elegant and efficient way to get get a list of @items from the controller which include a calculated sum of the amounts from corresponding transactions which would look something like this (with the total determined using sum)?

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<Item id: 1, category_id: 1, name: "Stella 16oz", description: "Stella Tall boys", created_at: "2014-10-29 18:05:26", updated_at: "2014-10-29 18:05:26", total: 74>, 
  #<Item id: 2, category_id: 2, name: "Wine Bottle", description: "Red or White", created_at: "2014-10-29 19:59:30", updated_at: "2014-10-30 18:23:48", total: 12>
]>
```

Instead of just this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<Item id: 1, category_id: 1, name: "Stella 16oz", description: "Stella Tall boys", created_at: "2014-10-29 18:05:26", updated_at: "2014-10-29 18:05:26">, 
  #<Item id: 2, category_id: 2, name: "Wine Bottle", description: "Red or White", created_at: "2014-10-29 19:59:30", updated_at: "2014-10-30 18:23:48">
]>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your controller code to this:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def current
    @items = Item.select('id, name, description').includes(:category, :transactions).all
  end

end
```

Then in view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.category.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.description %></td>
      <td><%= item.transactions.map(&:amount).sum %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Few things:

1. You might not want to call `.all` in controller while querying, as when data grows your page loading time will increase.
2. You might want to fix your broken [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) in view for `item.category.name` by having `delegate :name, :to => :category, :prefix => true` in your `Item` model class, so that in view you can just say: `<%= item.category_name %>`.
3. Making query in view is considered as a bad practice. You should always make queries like this: `<% sum = Transaction.where(item_id: item_id).sum(:amount) %>` in controller not in view.

Also you might want to have a method: `transaction_amount` like this in `Item` model class:

```
def transaction_amount
  transactions.map(&:amount).sum
end
```

So, that in view you can do: `<%= item.transaction_amount %>`

Then finally your view will look  like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.category_name %></td>
      <td><%= item.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.description %></td>
      <td><%= items.transaction_amount %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```